# How to upgrade npm on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: nodejs, npm

Following instructions here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node

I get the following results:

```
npm -v
3.10.10

npm install npm@latest -g

npm -v
3.10.10
```

According to the link above, the current stable version of npm is 5.6.0.

**Edit:**  For context, the reason I am trying to upgrade Node and npm is because I am installing [UIkit](https://getuikit.com/docs/installation) and their instructions said "Use Node.js version 8.2.0 or higher".

**Edit:**  I don't know if safe/best practise, but I did the following (there's a myriad of solutions out there, many seemed over complicated and not authoritative)

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
```

Then followed instructions from:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

and ran:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Now I get desired versions:

```
npm -v
5.6.0

node --version
v8.9.4
```